# How to format multiline RSpec expect {}.to change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Is there a better way to format this test to make it more readable?

```
expect { 
  within '.foo' do
    click_link 'Delete'
  end
}.to change {Foo.count}.by 1
```

expect `do...end` works, but is even uglier...

Comment: sorry, but what's wrong with this?

Comment: It doesn't seem very readable to me...and it uses {} for multiline block which isn't common...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
expected = expect do
  within '.foo' do
    click_link 'Delete'
  end
end

expected.to change { Foo.count }.by 1
```

Not exactly pretty, but reduces some of the line noise.

Answer (score 6):

Since putting everything in curly braces and on one line would be too long, I'd write it like this:

```
expect do
  within(".foo") { click_link "Delete" }
end.to change { Foo.count }.by 1
```

Update:
Not tested, but this should work too:

```
click_delete_link = lambda { within(".foo") { click_link "Delete" } } 
expect { click_delete_link }.to change { Foo.count }.by 1
```

But I still like the first version better :)

Comment: `end.to change` raises Rubocop offense/warning